# How to stop LEDs flickering when ESP32 is connected?

Tags: power-supply, led, pwm, esp32, decoupling-capacitor

I'm working on a circuit that consists of an ESP32 and a series of LEDs connected to the same power supply. My problem is that when the ESP32 is using Wi-Fi, the LEDs start to flicker:

https://imgur.com/a/ArnMvT2

The circuit consists of a 12v power supply, which feeds 3 rows of 4 LEDs (3 volts, ~150 mA each), so 12 LEDs in total. In parallel with the LEDs, there is a 5v voltage regulator (LM7805) powering the ESP32. If that's a bit confusing, please take a look at the image:

[image: circuit representation]

- I'm using a breadboard to test everything (before ordering a PCB),
  but I've heard that breadboards have high resistance. Could that be a
  cause of flickering?
- I tried using capacitors (1uf and 100uf), but the difference was very
  small. I may have used the wrong capacitors, though (I have very
  little experience with electronics). What capacitors should I use?
- I intend to later control the LEDs using PWM. Would the capacitors
  interfere with the PWM?
- What should I try? Please help :)

**Thanks for the time and help!**

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Which kind of power supply you have, maybe it is wrong type or can't provide enough current.

Comment: @Justme I am using a pretty powerful power supply (the one shown in the video). I'm pretty sure that is not the problem. The problem is that ESP32's Wi-Fi consumes a lot of power in spikes. I don't know to make proper decoupling in this circuit.

Comment: Well, there is no series resistors for LEDs and no bypassing for the regulator. Any voltage drop in wiring based on current consumption change will radically change LED current and brightness.

Comment: LED brightness is pretty much proportional to the current through them. But they are very nonlinear devices, and small changes in voltage can cause large variations in current. It appears that you are making no effort at all to control the current through the LEDs -- not even a series resistor -- relying instead on voltage regulation, which is clearly inadequate in your setup, especially when the ESP32 draws large spikes of current when transmitting.

Comment: @DaveTweed and Justme thanks for the help! Forgive my extreme ignorance but I don’t quite understand the purpose of the series resistor. I though resistors were just a way of lowering voltage or current, not preventing spikes. I tried to google this but couldn’t find very clear information. Could you kindly explain that to me? Also, where should the resistor be placed in the circuit? And how can I determine the ideal resistance of this resistor? Thank you so much!

Comment: LEDs must always be used with some form of current limiting, usually a series resistor.  The advertised forward voltage of an LED should be considered as an estimate, as the forward voltage may vary between parts, and will definitely increase with increasing current.  For your "3 volt" 150 mA LEDs, you should use three LEDs and a 20 Ohm resistor in series across 12 volts.  The voltage across the resistor will vary with current, and will tend to keep the current near the intended 150 mA.

Comment: @PeterBennett I think I understand that now. Thank you! I just have a couple more questions: 1- Does the resistor have to be in series with the LEDs and not the voltage regulator? I'm asking this because I wouldn't like the LEDs' brightness to drop. 2- Is the series resistor sufficient to solve the issue, or should I use a capacitor too (and if so, where)? Again, please forgive my ignorance. Thank you!

Comment: There should be a resistor in series with each group of LEDs.  The resistor will drop the voltage as it controls the current.  You adjust the resistor value to get the desired LED current and therefore brightness.

Comment: @PeterBennett I tried using several resistor values, exactly the way you said, and it definitely helped with the flickering. However, there’s still noticeable flicker. I don’t really know what else to try.